# Why we use virtual Binding in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

What is difference between <--Ko with:arra()--> 
and <--ko foreach:array()--> i have some confusion on using these two.

```
<!-- ko with:CustStatusLog --> <a class="custStatus tipsyN" title="" data-bind="style:{background:CustStatusColor}"> <!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko foreach:CustStatusLog --> <a class="custStatus tipsyN" title="" data-bind="style:{background:CustStatusColor}"> <!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreach binding and with binding is more or less same. Both Binding did the same operation.

we can access the elements by using $parents and $root in both the bindings